# When using a groupby, how to use a different table's column as group key?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table `tariff_groups`:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Green tariffs |
| 2 | Blue tariffs |
| 3 | Red tariffs |

and I have a table `things_usage_tariffs` that define which things use which tariffs of a tariff group:

| id | thing_id | tariff_group | description | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Nice tariff of the Green group. | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | Even nicer tariff of the Green group. | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | Best green tariff. | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | Cool blue tariff. | 3 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | Amazing red tariff. | 4 |

With this code I get all the tariffs that `thing` with `id` 1 has:

```
$tariffs = DB::table('things_usage_tariffs')
    ->where(
        [
            'thing_id' => $id,
        ]
    )
    ->orderBy('delta', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('tariff_group')
    ;
```

Which returns:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1257 ▼
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1247 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▶]
    }
    2 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1253 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    3 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1246 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
}
```

Which is cool, but I would like to know how to change the query that I directly get:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1257 ▼
    'Green tariffs' => array(4)
    'Blue tariffs' => array(1)
    'Red tariffs' => array(1)
}
```

I know I could iterate through the result and replace the numeric keys with their respective tariff group name, but for that I would need to make another statement that gets the names and I feel this could be done with a join. Any ideas?

Comment: One easy way is to use eloquent with proper relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With eloquent and proper relationships:

Two models:

```
class TariffGroup extends Model{
   public function thingsUsageTariffs(){
     return $this->hasMany(ThingsUsageTariff::class, 'tariff_group', 'id');
   }
}
class ThingsUsageTariff extends Model{
   public function tariffGroup(){
     return $this->belongsTo(TariffGroup::class, 'id', 'tariff_group');
   }
}
```

Now in your controller:

```
$tariffs = TariffGroup::with(['thingsUsageTariffs' => function($query){
  return $query->orderBy('delta', 'asc');
}])->get();
```

should yield something similar to what you want to achieve.

---

If you want to use tables without models, one approach would be to join the tables then apply group by and `keyBy` to define keys for the groups:

```
$tariffs = DB::table('things_usage_tariffs')
   ->join('tariff_groups', 'tariff_groups.id', '=', 'things_usage_tariffs.tariff_group')
   ->orderBy('things_usage_tariffs.delta', 'asc')
   ->get()
   ->groupBy('tariff_group')
   ->map(function ($group) { 
        return $group->keyBy('name'); 
   });
```

This yield should be closer to the result you want.

Note: Name must be unique since we are assigning it as keys. Also, this code is not tested, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: So its not really easy without using Models? With just the query builder?

Comment: also, this gives "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" error.

Comment: @Alex fixed with method to fix that error.

Comment: @Alex also added an alternative method that does not use models.

Comment: thanks for your effort. i did end up creating a model for the tariffs and using pivots i kind of am near to what i need.